# How does Gitlab CI determine if a PHPUnit test pass or fails?

Tags: php, unit-testing, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I have this basic `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
image: php:7.2

before_script:
  # install git
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install git -yqq
  # Install composer
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  # Install all project dependencies
  - php composer.phar install


tests:
  script:
    - vendor/bin/phpunit tests
```

This works just fine, it alerts me if unit tests fail or pass.

My question is how exactly does Gitlab CI know this? Do they parse the output of PHPUnit and see if the string `FAILURES!` exist?

Comment: A script returning any other exit code than 0 is treat as failed.

Comment: @SaschaFrinken Can you kindly explain in brief what exit codes are in relation to PHPUnit? Do you mean to say PHPUnit internally returns 0 or 1? How does Gitlab CI read it? The output of PHPUnit for a human is just `Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1` or `OK (1 test, 1 assertion)`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: @SaschaFrinken I'm aware of that but my question is how does that relate to Gitlab CI? It seems it magically knows if the tests fails or pass. What if I'm using a home-brewed or private testing software, I want to know how Gitlab CI would know if I'm returning a pass or fail test.

Comment: Your unit test is just a script that will return `0`  as exit code when all tests pass. CI checks the return code and handles it as failed or passed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The gitlab-ci only checks the exit codes of processes running inside it. If a process exits with another status code than 0 then the pipeline stops and declares failure. That's how the CI pipelines works overall, not only gitlab but Jenkins, etc. too.

Comment: Ok so if I have a home-brewed tester script I simply `echo 1;` or `echo  0;` for pass and fails?

Comment: No, `echo` does only print to stdout string you pass to it. For passing and failing CI it would be `exit 0` and `exit 1`.

Comment: You mean literately using `exit(0);` or `exit(1);`

Comment: Yes. My example was from bash that's why it is without brackets.

Comment: I see that. Never knew `exit();` had a special purpose other than terminating the script execution.